# How to display Elan transcription in wavesurfer.js?

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

I'm trying to use [wavesurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/elan/index.html) to create a web app, and I can't figure out how to display the transcript/caption using their Elan plugin.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.1.2/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.1.2/plugin/wavesurfer.elan.min.js"></script>
```

The following is the script for the plugin.

```
<body>
    <div id="waveform"></div>

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
                            Play/Pause
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="annotations"></div>
    
    <script>

        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: document.querySelector('#waveform'),
            progressColor: "black",
            waveColor: 'gray',
            loop: true,
            scrollParent: true,
            maxCanvasWidth: 500,
            mediaControls: true,        
            minPxPerSec: 75,
            hideScrollbar: false
        });   
        
        wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
            var elan = Object.create(WaveSurfer.ELAN);
            elan.init({
                wavesurfer: wavesurfer,
                url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/master/example/elan/transcripts/001z.xml',
                container: "#annotations",
                tiers: {
                    Text: true,
                    Comments: false
                }           
            });
        });
        
        wavesurfer.load('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/master/example/elan/transcripts/001z.mp3');       
    
        </script> 
  
    </body>
```

I couldn't find any working example of this except in the wavesurfer.js website. Could someone tell me what am I missing? Perhaps it has something to do with my script being incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is a [working example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/mostafa-es/pen/bGBYgbz?editors=1010)

There is also `region plugin` in case that you want to use it.

I'm going to explain it below :

### step 1 : HTML setup

Add the related CDN links to your html file.
You can just skip the second script if you don't want that `region`.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.elan.js"></script>
```

Then we need two containers. One of them for `waveform` and the other one for `annotations`. There is also a play/pause button.

```
<div class="wave-container">
  <div id="waveform"></div>
</div>

<button class="toggle" onCLick="togglePlay()">play/pause</button>

<div id="annotations" class="table-responsive"></div>
```

### Step 2 : JS configs

First of all we are going to define the `WaveSurfer` player and add the `Elan` plugin to its config. after that you can load a MP3 as an example.

```
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: 'violet',
    progressColor: 'purple',
    backend: 'MediaElement',
    plugins: [
      WaveSurfer.elan.create({
        url: 'https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/elan/transcripts/001z.xml',
        container: '#annotations',
        tiers: {
          Text: true,
          Comments: true
        }
      }),
      WaveSurfer.regions.create()
    ]
});
```

Now you have Elan transcription on your screen. Let's add a `select` event to handle the click on every transcript.

```
wavesurfer.elan.on('select', function(start, end) {
  wavesurfer.backend.play(start, end);
});
```

Finally, we're going to handle the regions on `audioprocess` event.

```
let prevAnnotation, prevRow, region;
let onProgress = function(time) {
  let annotation = wavesurfer.elan.getRenderedAnnotation(time);

  if (prevAnnotation != annotation) {
    prevAnnotation = annotation;

    region && region.remove();
    region = null;

    if (annotation) {
      // Highlight annotation table row
      let row = wavesurfer.elan.getAnnotationNode(annotation);
      prevRow && prevRow.classList.remove('success');
      prevRow = row;
      row.classList.add('success');
      let before = row.previousSibling;
      if (before) {
        wavesurfer.elan.container.scrollTop = before.offsetTop;
      }

      // Region
      region = wavesurfer.addRegion({
        start: annotation.start,
        end: annotation.end,
        resize: false,
        color: 'rgba(223, 240, 216, 0.7)'
      });
    }
  }
};

wavesurfer.on('audioprocess', onProgress);
```